# JSX array.map undefined boolean data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

i tried to display & map my objects in a table row, but my boolean datas will return as undefined and i can't even convert them into strings, whats the solution?

Look at user.isenable and user.isonline in mapping ...

this is what i tried ...

```
import { component, Fragment } from 'react'

class Users extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      users: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = "http://localhost:4000/api/user";
    // AXIOS REQUEST
    axios.get(url).then(res => {
      this.setState({ users: res.data });
      console.log(this.state.users);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const users = this.state;
    console.log(this.state.users.isenbale);
    return (
      <table id="users">
        <tr>
          <th>is Enable</th>
          <th>is Online</th>
        </tr>

        {this.state.users.map(user => {
          return (
            <tr key={user.nationalcode}>
              <td>{user.isEnable.toString()}</td>
              <td>{user.isOnline.toString()}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

console logs of `res.data` & `this.state.users` are the same.

```js
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {nationalcode: 134556778, stockcode: "md3456", firstname: "ali", lastname: "khodabakhashi", isenable: true, …}
1: {nationalcode: 1334853905, stockcode: "md4f5789", firstname: "saeed", lastname: "mohammad", isenable: true, …}
2: {nationalcode: 11313, stockcode: "31313", firstname: "1313", lastname: "1313", isenable: null, …}
3: {nationalcode: 4151515, stockcode: "151", firstname: "5131", lastname: "3114", isenable: null, …}
4: {nationalcode: 123456789, stockcode: "3131", firstname: "31", lastname: "3131", isenable: null, …}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `console.log(this.state.users);`

Comment: I think `const users = this.state;` should be `const { users } = this.state;`

Comment: Can you post the console log of `res.data`?

Comment: @Jacob i added to question

Comment: @izambl added ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the data, you're receiving `isenable` is all lowercase but in the code, you're using it as `isEnable`, javascript variable names are case sensitive so the engine treat them as two different things.

Change the code to `user.isenable` and it should work

Answer (score 0):

There is two issues.

1. In the example users object you provided it is `isenable` with lowercase. However, you are trying to reference `isEnable`
2. Some of your `isenable` fields are `null`. This does not have a toString method

As null is falsy, you can short circuit it.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-ishizaka-kd1pm) is an example